# Error in windows file mfreadwrite.h

Tags: c++, .net, windows

I have a project where I have to use the functions of "mfreadwrite.h", but when I try to compile my project I get these errors:

```
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(260): error C2065: 'IMFMediaSource': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(260): error C2065: 'pMediaSource': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(261): error C2065: 'pAttributes': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(261): error C2275: 'IMFAttributes': illegal use of this type as an expression
5>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\mfobjects.h(310): note: see declaration of 'IMFAttributes'
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(262): error C2065: 'ppSourceReader': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(262): error C2275: 'IMFSourceReader': illegal use of this type as an expression
5>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(52): note: see declaration of 'IMFSourceReader'
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(262): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(1000): error C2065: 'IMFMediaSink': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(1000): error C2065: 'pMediaSink': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(1001): error C2065: 'pAttributes': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(1001): error C2275: 'IMFAttributes': illegal use of this type as an expression
5>  c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.1\include\um\mfobjects.h(310): note: see declaration of 'IMFAttributes'
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(1002): error C2065: 'ppSinkWriter': undeclared identifier
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(1002): error C2275: 'IMFSinkWriter': illegal use of this type as an expression
5>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\mfreadwrite.h(73): note: see declaration of 'IMFSinkWriter'
```

can anyone help me please?

ps:

I tried cleaning and rebuilding my project a couple of times but I still get the errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and the solution for me was including `mfidl.h`  before every `mfreadwrite.h` include directives.

It can be tricky, because the compiler output might be misleading when the file causing the problem is included into another file.

The easiest way I found to track the problem back to the source was showing the included files in the compile output window. (*Project /  Properties / Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Advanced / Show Includes <- set it to Yes*)

I started going back from the first error message and checked the custom headers and source files (the ones I wrote).

Environment: Windows 8.1/64b, Visual Studio 2015 Express for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Thanks!, I put The project away but now I can continue

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where I was trying to get a project to compile in Visual Studio 2010 that used the IMFSinkWriter. It compiled fine with Visual Studio 2013, but for 2010 I had to place the following in the stdafx.h file:

```
#define WINVER 0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0X0601
```